# Interrupt and restart a setTimeOut sequence of events with jquery?

Tags: jquery, sequence, settimeout, interrupt

Sorry if this makes no sense, I am a complete beginner!

Basically i am trying to get a sequence of texts to fade in then out one after the other until finally the last one appears and stays static. However, i want the sequence to be interrupted if the user moves the mouse/keyboard before the last text has appeared. I'd like the text "begin again" to appear and then the sequence to begin again.

This is what I've come up with so far. But I'm not sure how to code the interruption!

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text1').fadeIn();",1000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text1').fadeOut();",5000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text2').fadeIn();",6000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text2').fadeOut();",10000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text3').fadeIn();",11000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text3').fadeOut();",15000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text4').fadeIn();",16000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text4').fadeOut();",20000 );
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#text5').fadeIn();",21000 );

});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="startagain" class=hidden">Start Again!</div>
<div id="text1" class="hidden">Text 1</div>
<div id="text2" class="hidden">Text 2</div>
<div id="text3" class="hidden">Text 3</div>
<div id="text4" class="hidden">Text 4</div>
<div id="text5" class="hidden">Text 5</div>
```

Any help really appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sarah
Unable to post code in the comment back so here ya go:

```
function runIt(){
$('#myText').hover(function(){
        $(this).clearQueue().html('Start Again');

    })
    .click(function(){
        runIt();
    })
    .html('text 1')
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).html('text 2');
    })
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).html('text 3').unbind('hover');
    })
    .fadeIn(1000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks David, it's working now! The only problm I am having is the hover is still triggering "start again" on text3. Is there a way to stop that? Sorry blonde moment :/

Comment: @Sarah thats great Sarah! Please feel free to accept the answer as that is how stack overflow works best!

Answer (score 1):

Your basic setting and clearing of timers...

```
//sets the timer for 1 second (same syntax as setInterval)
var timer = setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1000);

//clears the timer, the function will never get called.
clearInterval(timer);
```

If you are queueing up animations, its best to use callback functions instead of timers, like so:

```
//#text1 will fadeOut immediately following it fading in.
$('#text1').fadeIn(function() {
  //occurs after the first animation is complete
  //this refers to #text1
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this effect by taking advantage of jquery's animation queue like so

HTML:

```
<div id="myText"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    runIt();

});

function runIt(){
$('#myText').hover(function(){
        $(this).clearQueue().html('Start Again');

    })
    .click(function(){
        runIt();
    })
    .html('text 1')
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).html('text 2');
    })
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).html('text 3');
    })
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).html('start again');
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks David! Is there a way to make text 3 remain on screen (no fadeOut) and not be affected by mouse movement?

Comment: Sure you can just remove the last step and also the hover event when you get there like so:


`code`function runIt(){
$('#myText').hover(function(){
        $(this).clearQueue().html('Start Again');

    })
    .click(function(){
        runIt();
    })
    .html('text 1')
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).html('text 2');
    })
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).html('text 3').unbind('hover');
    });
};

Comment: @Sarah see my other response since the code posting didnt work for me in a comment.